# jquery plugin - asRange / I want to vertical bar

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, range

I want to vertical bar...
but this option not working

what i worte -->

```
$(".range-example-5").asRange({
step: 0.1,
range: false,
min: 0,
max: 10,
direction:'v'});
```

from api..
'direction' is an option that specifies the vertical and horizontal.

```
direction   : 'v'   Optional property, set the direction for the progress bar ,'v' for vertical and 'h' for horizontal
```

do you know anyone?

Answer (score -1):

This options is not working. 
This is issue for asRange

https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asRange/issues/8

but i got a request...it will take time ^_^....